# Replacing characters after string

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

```
S-123-P Bash Pocket Ref.        2010    Cengage Learning    $55
E-P234  Python Pocket Ref.      2012    Cengage Learning    $45
55-MNP  Unix System Programming 2001    Sybex               $230
```

I need to replace the numbers after the `$` not including the `$` with `*`, so the output need to be:

```
S-123-P Bash Pocket Ref.        2010    Cengage Learning    $**
E-P234  Python Pocket Ref.      2012    Cengage Learning    $**
55-MNP  Unix System Programming 2001    Sybex               $***
```

I've been able to replace the last digit or last 2, but not every digit after the `$`.
I've tried `sed` and `awk` gsub but nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: Just an advice: if you want realy anonymize the price then it could be better to change any price to the same count of stars. ($1 -> $** as the $123 -> $**).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed` and advantage of not touching the Tabs/Spaces or fields intention:

```
sed -E ':a s/(\$\**)[^*]/\1*/; ta' infile
```

replace every `($<zero-or-more-*>)[<non-*-character>]` with `$<zero-or-more-*><plus-additional-*-added>` (`\1*`; `\1` is the back-reference to the first matched group in `sed` defining by `(...)`) until all `<non-*-character>`s replaced with `*`s.

---

A bit complex, but in case you wanted to force the changes only on the last field, you could use the command in this way:

```
sed -E ':a s/(\$\**)[^*]([^$]*)$/\1*\2/; ta' infile
```

Comment: Do you have any idea why `awk '{ print gensub ("$[0-9]+","$*", "g"); }` does not work? The `$` seems to confuse `awk`.

Comment: you have a `awk` answer also here you can take a look. your awk problem is because you are not setting the gensub substitution to any field to update the changes as well as you need double escape the dollar `\\$`, so `gawk '{$NF=gensub("\\$[0-9]+","$*", "g", $NF); print }' infile`, but as you see it does replace all digits with single `*`

Comment: OK, thanks.  I thought I had tried double escaping but apparently not.

Answer (score 4):

With awk / gsub - assuming that we may replace any decimal digit in the last field, provided it begins with `$` i.e. we don't need to handle things like `123$45 -> 123$**`:

```
awk '$NF ~ /\$[0-9]+/ {gsub(/[0-9]/,"*",$NF)} 1' file
```

Comment: to keep the fields intention you can force the awk to use filed separator as regex for example with `awk -F'(\t)'` or `awk -F'\t|'` and change the OFS to tab for sure, or if it's space it's the same `-F' |'` or ...

Comment: or even you can  define the filed separator to `$` to be able to handle the things like `123$45` you mentioned `awk -F'$' '$NF ~ /[0-9]+/ {gsub(/[0-9]/,"*",$NF)} 1' OFS='$' infile`

Answer (score 2):

Perl gives a nice way to do this if you have it available:

```
perl -lpe 's/\$([0-9]*)/"\$" . "*" x length($1)/e'
```

This takes advantage of the ability to have the replacement portion of a regex substitution be a Perl expression rather than a fixed string (the `/e` flag) to produce the appropriate number of asterisks on demand, instead of requiring a "repeat until done" loop.

Comment: That should be `perl -lpe 's/\$([0-9]*)/"\$" . "*" x length($1)/e'` to handle an input like `a $123 bar`, where the dollar sum is not at the end. The way you posted it, it would change that to `a $*******`, replacing the space and `bar`, too.

Comment: @ilkkachu yeah, that works too. Problem spec was unclear, and no test cases covered that :)